# Different outcomes for similar requests to github's api

Tags: rest, github

I'm trying to query issues from github.
In the first URL I am looking for all the issues that have `good first issue` and `help wanted` in its labels.
In the second URL I am looking only for issues with `good first issue`.
The thing is that I sort both of the results by the time they are created.
I don't understand how can it be that the first result for the first URL is different from the first result in the second URL? O_o

The second URL should cover both of the results, which will mean that the first result of the second URL should also be the firs result of the first URL, but that is not the case.
How exactly does the API of github works then?

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=language:python+label:%22good%20first%20issue%22+label:%22help%20wanted%22+state:open&sort=created

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=language:python+label:%22good%20first%20issue%22+state:open&sort=created

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which will mean that the first result of the second URL should also be the firs result of the first URL

The second URL can show issues with the label "good first issue" created *before* any issue with a label "`good first issue` + `help wanted`" returned by the first URL.

In that regard, the first result of the second URL won't be the first result of the first URL.

So the second URL results, while including the first one results, might do so with a different list at the beginning.